# Kivy: package app with error gstplayer playbin

Tags: python, kivy, gstreamer, pyinstaller

I created a windows package kivy(1.9.1) using PyInstaller(3.2) and I followed the instructions from the documentation but when I run the .exe get the message error "Unable to create a playbin".

I have the Kivy dependencies installed and the GStreamer thoungh.
Someone can help me?

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\sites-packages\kivy\core\audio\audio\__init__.py", line 161, in on_source
self.load()
File "C:\Python34\lib\sites-packages\kivy\core\audio\audio\audio_gstplayer.py", line 82, in load
self.player.load()
File "kivy\lib\gstplayer\_gstplayer.pyx", line 233, in kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayer.load (kivy\lib/gstplayer\_gstplayer.c:2791)
kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayerException: Unable to create a playbin Failed to execute script main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a issue in the PyInstaller. Link below:

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4931